# Removing "selected" atttribute from cloned select options not working in IE

Tags: jquery, attributes, html-select, selected

I have written a plugin that converts a `<select multiple>` into multiple, mutually exclusive, single `<select>`s.

The initial HTML rendered has multiple `<option selected>` which were set *server-side*:

```
<select id="template" style="display: none;" multiple="">
    <option value="1">One</option>
    <option value="2" selected="">Two</option>
    <option value="3">Three</option>
    <option value="4" selected="">Four</option>
    <option value="5">Five</option>
    <option value="6" selected="">Six</option>
    <option value="7">Seven</option>
</select>
```

When I clone the `<option>`s to a series of new lists (one per selected option), I noticed that `removeAttr("selected")` was not removing the selected attribute in IE only:

e.g. this code:

```
$('#template').children().clone().removeAttr('selected').appendTo($select);
```

results in this in the DOM on IE:

```
<li class="listClass">
    <select class="selectClass">
        <option value="1">One</option>
        <option value="2" selected="">Two</option>
        <option value="3">Three</option>
        <option value="4" selected="">Four</option>
        <option value="5">Five</option>
        <option value="6" selected="">Six</option>
        <option value="7">Seven</option>
    </select>
</li>
```

but shows it correctly in Chrome:

```
<li class="listClass">
    <select class="selectClass">
        <option value="1">One</option>
        <option value="2">Two</option>
        <option value="3">Three</option>
        <option value="4">Four</option>
        <option value="5">Five</option>
        <option value="6">Six</option>
        <option value="7">Seven</option>
    </select>
</li>
```

Here is a mockup: http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/t9p2bgt0/1/ Try it with Chrome and IE to see the difference in their respective DOM inspectors.

I realise this will not affect the operation of the new lists, but I would prefer to cleanup the `<option>`s html when they are cloned, so need to know if there is a workaround.

**Notes:**

- Using `prop('selected', false)` instead, only changes the internal state and the attributes are left there (in IE *and* in Chrome).
- Using `removeProp('selected')` has no effect on the DOM.

Comment: is still respecting value being that of first option as would be expected of non selected options

Comment: @charlietfl: If you mean does it still work as a list, yes. I just want to clean up the HTML (if only for debugging purposes).

Comment: actually that was a statement  , not sure that you really have a problem

Comment: @charlietfl: Before your edit it read like a question :) The problem is the HTML is bloated with extra `selected=""` that are ignored which gets in the way of DOM inspections. Yes I will live with it, if I have too, but was hoping someone would know a solution (I can think of 2 solutions so far).

Comment: if it's bothersome could map value/text to new html string. I think it's more of an issue of Dev tools not showing accurate state when compared to value or property `selected`

Comment: @charlietfl: That is part of one option (to create fresh `<option>` with the key and value only).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `defaultSelected` instead of `selected`, and use `prop` to set it to null instead of using `removeAttr`.

**Example 1:**

This attempts to clear `selected`, and the alert still shows the `selected` options:

```js
$('#template').children().prop('selected', null);
alert($('#template').html());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="template" style="display: none;" multiple="">
    <option value="1">One</option>
    <option value="2" selected="">Two</option>
    <option value="3">Three</option>
    <option value="4" selected="">Four</option>
    <option value="5">Five</option>
    <option value="6" selected="">Six</option>
    <option value="7">Seven</option>
</select>
```

**Example 2:**

This clears `defaultSelected`, which successfully clears the `selected` options:

```js
$('#template').children().prop('defaultSelected', null);
alert($('#template').html());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="template" style="display: none;" multiple="">
    <option value="1">One</option>
    <option value="2" selected="">Two</option>
    <option value="3">Three</option>
    <option value="4" selected="">Four</option>
    <option value="5">Five</option>
    <option value="6" selected="">Six</option>
    <option value="7">Seven</option>
</select>
```

Comment: At last a solution that works and is not a workaround (like my own answer) :) Thanks.

Comment: This was tricky.  I looked at all object properties, and `defaultSelected` jumped out at me.  It's not very well documented.

Comment: That is exactly what I needed. I went back to using `clone().prop('defaultSelected', null).appendTo($select)` and it works perfectly (and faster than my workaround). :)

Answer (score 0):

Until someone says otherwise, it appears to be a flaw in IE that you cannot remove the `selected` attributes from the DOM on `<option>` elements.

My first workaround is to create new  elements with the key and text value e.g.

```
$('#template').children().each(function(){
    $select.append($('<option>', {'value': $(this).val(), text: $(this).text()}));
});
```

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/t9p2bgt0/4/

The second would be a text replace of the offending string in the HTML of the new target `<select>`, but I cannot come up with a reliable version of this one.